# exit command in Python not triggered/no error but code logic not correct

Tags: python

The desired behavior of the code is to trigger the exit command once counter1 == 3. Unfortunately, counter1 can go above 3 and the exit command will not be triggered.

```
counter1 = 0

while True:
  player1 = input("Player 1 > ")
  player2 = input("Player 2 > ")
  if player1 == "R" and player2 == "S":
    print("Player 1 wins")
    print(counter1)
    counter1 +=1
    continue
  else:
    print("Uhh.. try again")
  if counter1 == 3:
    print("Player 1 won the game")
    exit()
```

If player 1 wins more than 3 times (which is monitored by counter1), exit command should be activated.

Comment: You have a `continue` statement right after `counter1 += 1`, which means you bypass the check for `if counter1 == 3`.

Comment: Hello, I am not sure why are you using the `continue` statement, can you. remove it and execute one more time your script?

Comment: This seems like *too* minimal an example: "rock-beats-scissor" is just one of three ways to win, and you never check if `player2` is the winner player instead of `player1`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments of Iarsks and Franco Gil I will give you a more thorough explanation.

The counter is only updated when `player1` wins. The best would be to check now whether `counter1 == 3` and then quit the program. Currently, you continue the game loop every time the `player1` wins and therefore "jump over" the if statement with which you check whether the game is finished. There are two possibilities to resolve your issue:

1. Remove the `continue` if the `player1` wins, so the if statement at the end of the game loop will be evaluated.
2. Put the second if statement into the first if statement and delete the continue.